# Window Manager not displaying anything on my device

Tags: android, overlay, android-windowmanager, window-managers

I've been trying to use the Window Manager to display a view over other applications but whenever I tap on start nothing happens on my device.
I've looked at other guides and tutorials but for some reason I can't get it to display on my device (Pocophone F1 Android Pie). When I change the parameter type to TYPE_PHONE and run it on a lower API it works fine. When I set it to TYPE_APPLICATION OVERLAY and run it on a higher API it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any help.

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notify_me"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Service" />
</LinearLayout>
```

popup.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popupText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THIS IS TEXT FOR TESTING PURPOSES." />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION = 2084;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        } else {
            initializeView();
        }
    }

    private void initializeView() {
        findViewById(R.id.notify_me).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                initializeView();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Draw over other app permission not available. Closing the application",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                finish();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private WindowManager wm;
    private View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        view=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popup,null);
        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x=0;
        params.y=0;

        wm.addView(view, params);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        wm.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to make a service use the WindowManager to add a UI?

Comment: I thought that if you wanted to keep the app running after closing that you would need a service. Would it make a difference if I put it in the MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting activity for result, you are passing 0 as a result code while on call back of **onActivityResulty** you are checking result code against **CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION**. That does not make sense. Please change this with **0** or pass **CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION** while calling **startActivityForResult()** method. Hope this makes sense. If still you have a problem, please let me know.

Comment: I changed it to CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION but it still doesnt display the popup when I tap on the Start Service button.